# how to fix error MSB3021: Unable to copy file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working now with asp.net mvc
I am facing this annoying issue where the app not running although it was running I made some changes and restarted it sadly got this

[image]

and I got this message from the antivirus before it get stopped
"we've blocked ViewModel.exe because it was infected with IDP.Generic"

this problem will go once I restart my device which is not an ideal solution
I think there is a task running in the back
or the antivirus is stopping my app for some reason
I opened processes and I couldn't know which one it

Comment: You need to add the folder to your antivirus exclusions list. Or just the exe itself

Comment: The folder makes it look like an ASP.NET app. Is the ASP.NET app running the EXE for some reason?